# Node.js unresponsive until key press on console

Tags: node.js, console, socket.io

I have a Node.js app, that runs on a Windows Server 2008. I'm facing a weird problem here.

My app does more than one async tasks. Sending data to socket.io, MySQL, HTTP connections, TCP connections etc.

My Node app becomes unresponsive especially on the socket.io end, and only starts responding back again after any key press on the console. Is this a known issue? Any bypasses around such a behavior?

Note: I am using console.log heavily to keep track of the current operation and errors in process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a bit of a background check and came to the following conclusions.

The Powershell console on Windows Server 2008 goes on a 'pause' mode when clicked on it. It is released again if you click elsewhere.
http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/112032-script-pauses-when-you-click-powershell-text-window.html

If you notice, `console.log` is async. But `console.warn` and `console.error` are blocking. These are not async.

The console pause might block some/most part of the Node.js operations. Esp. as Socket.io at default debugging level will report with more than just `console.log`.

Comment: Better answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in a Windows Machine with my Node.js server running on PowerShell.

I solved it disabling Quick Edit Mode and Insert options in the Properties panel of PowerShell. It seems like pause the process when you click on the terminal with those two options enabled.

Hope this helps you, bro.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions that other people have suggested didn't work for me, but using [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) to start the script solved it. Definitely appears to be a console application problem, rather than a node.js problem.