# Nodejs web server goes idle when not in direct use

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a simple express https web server, serving to my local network. Running on a windows 10 machine, this server is able to make connections with all devices on my lan without any problems. That is until a couple minutes pass by and the server seemingly goes idle, ceasing to responding to any requests made by any devices. Hitting enter in the console fixes this problem but is not preferable. Is there a way to keep node running at all times? I am sadly not able to switch to a different os, if this is some sort of windows task focusing feature then I would presumably be out of luck.

Server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const ip = require("ip");

const app = express();
const port = 443;

//determines what folder houses js, css, html, etc files - console.log the ip of a connected client 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"), function (req, res, next) {
  const ip = req.ip;

  console.log("Now serving ip:", "\x1b[33m", ip, "\x1b[37m");
  next();
});

//determines which file is the index
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});

var sslServer = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "certificate", "key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "certificate", "certificate.pem")
    ),
  },
  app
);

//determines which port server should listen on - console.log when server has successfully started
sslServer.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(
    "Server has successfully started, available on:",
    "\x1b[33m",
    ip.address(),
    "\x1b[37m",
    "listening on port:",
    "\x1b[33m",
    +port,
    "\x1b[37m"
  );
  console.log("CTRL + C to exit server");
});
```

Will provide any needed information.

Comment: Are you using powershell?

Comment: Node doesn't "go idle" - this sounds like an OS issue

Comment: Server shouldn't go idle like others have mentioned, sounds like an OS issue to me too. Can you please try using any process managing service, for example : https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service

Comment: Could be related to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557850/node-js-unresponsive-until-key-press-on-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in Powershell. It halts the execution upon clicking on the command window until the user presses Enter. Open the Power Shell Properties and untick "Quick Edit Mode" and "Insert Mode".

[image]